# ssh: connect to host xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: 18.04, server, ssh, openssh, sftp

I am using ubuntu in my old pc and laptop.

Whenever I connect to my note book from pc by using `ssh` and `sftp` it works.

```
pc to notebook >> no problem
```

Now I am trying to make my pc like a remote server.

So I am getting problem when I try to connect to pc from notebook.

```
notebook to pc connection
ssh: connect to host xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 22: Connection timed out
```

```
I checked follwoing to conform:
internet connection --ok
ipaddress - correct
ssh server(on both pc) -- on
ufw on both pc -- allowed
```

but I am still not able to solve this issue.
Any suggestion??

Comment: `Connection timed out` means the the client couldn't find the server. Most commonly, that suggests a wrong IP address. Check it again.